# How to initialize multiple instance of Amyuni Pdf library?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I am using Amyuni pdf library from a windows service, which service is running as a LocalSystem Account . Following is the code i am using for printing .

```
 private void Initialize()
    {
        acPDFCreatorLib.Initialize();
        acPDFCreatorLib.SetLicenseKey(licenseTo, activationCode);
    }
```

...... Print pdf

```
using (FileStream file1 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                using (IacDocument doc1 = new IacDocument())
                {
                    doc1.Open(file1, "");
                    doc1.AttributeByName("Title").Value = documentName;
                    doc1.SetAttributeForMultipleSelection("UnicodeFonts", true, false);
                    doc1.Copies = printEvent.Copies;
                    bool printed = doc1.Print(printerName, false);
                    PrintSystemJobInfo PrintSystemJobInfo = GetPrintJob(printerName, fileName);
                    if (printed)
                    {
                        Logger.Log(string.Format("[AMYUNI]  PDF' {0} ' printed using printer {1}", documentName, printerName));
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

For some printers 'doc1.Print(printerName, false);' in not working and it is not returning a result.The thread used to invoke print function is never returning . So we can not identify an error .

So now, the solution we are planning is initializing amyuni library instance for each printer in different threads . With this we will be able to make our solution work for other printers even if its is blocked by a single printer (amyuni library freezes of don't respond).

For this **how we can initialize multiple instances of library ?**

Answer (score 3):

This call stays as is, **but in the main thread only**:

```
private void Initialize()
    {
        acPDFCreatorLib.Initialize();
        acPDFCreatorLib.SetLicenseKey(licenseTo, activationCode);
    }
```

and the remaining part goes in separate threads:

```
using (FileStream file1 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                using (IacDocument doc1 = new IacDocument())
                {
                    doc1.Open(file1, "");
                    doc1.AttributeByName("Title").Value = documentName;
                    doc1.SetAttributeForMultipleSelection("UnicodeFonts", true, false);
                    doc1.Copies = printEvent.Copies;
                    bool printed = doc1.Print(printerName, false);
                    PrintSystemJobInfo PrintSystemJobInfo = GetPrintJob(printerName, fileName);
                    if (printed)
                    {
                        Logger.Log(string.Format("[AMYUNI]  PDF' {0} ' printed using printer {1}", documentName, printerName));
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

Depending on your workflow you may need to make sure that the PDF Creator IacDocument instance is not disposed before the printing is finished for that instance.

*Disclaimer: This answer was provided by an employee of Amyuni Technologies.*

Comment: We already using this is in separate threads. Execution log is as follows . 
-[Thread 11]Initializing acPDFCreatorLib
-[Thread 14] Printing PDF '
-[Thread 5]Initializing acPDFCreatorLib
-[Thread 15] Printing PDF '

But it seems in high level it is using same reference which I created when we initializing using `acPDFCreatorLib.Initialize();`
Because of this if acPDFCreatorLib crashed for a printer based on an issue on that printer it stops working for other printers as well.  Can you explain how it worked here

Comment: @charithsoori If your printer is using the spooler service, then if one print-job crashes, all other pending jobs will meet the same fate.

Comment: "But it seems in high level it is using same reference" I do not understand what you mean with that... you are creating the instances of the document class, so only you can tell if you are using the same reference in all threads or not.

Comment: By the way, you are not supposed to call acPDFCreatorLib.Initialize() on every thread, you should call it just once in the main thread before creating  the first document instance.

Comment: Our issue is we have one special printer which need "White Background enabled". If we don’t do that our application stop printing for all printers not only that printer. Since it stops for all printers our assumption is Amyuni library crashes. And we cannot identify it because it is not returning or giving an exception.
Because of this right now we need our application is fully isolated from Amyuni library. By doing that we expect if Amyuni library stops working like above for one printer it will still work for other printers.

Comment: And what we thought on having multiple Amyuni library instances for each printer.
What I meant by "But it seems in high level it is using same reference" is, even if we call doc.printer() in multiple thread(Thread for each printer) if it stops for one thread/printer it will stop working for all. So our assumption is it is creating only one instance/reference/(singleton)

Comment: I can assure you that the document class is not a singleton object. There are indeed singleton objects used by all instances of this class, but they are related to system resources (like a collection of fonts installed on the system for example), and the printer handle is not one of them.

Comment: @janitha000 Additionally, if there is indeed an issue with this particular printer we will like to have the opportunity to fix it, please send to support at amyuni dot com the details about the printer (model and version of the driver) that you are using, together with a few sample PDF files if possible and will take a look. Maybe configuring the driver as "print to file" will suffice to reproduce the problem.